# C How would I break out of the loop with EOF?

Tags: c

My program essentially asks the user to enter an undefined amount of floats and I wish for the program to output the smallest value, largest value, and the mean of the values upon the user entering EOF.

Right now the loop exits and outputs the smallest value, largest value, and mean when the user enters a number <= -100,000 or => 100,000, of which is the restrictions the program imposes on the user's input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{


    float sum, smallest, largest;
    float value, average,check;
    int count;

    sum = 0.000000;
    count = 0;
    check = scanf(" %f",&value);
    smallest = value;
    largest = value;

    while (value >= -100000 && value <= 100000)
    {
        sum += value;
        count++;
        if (value > largest)
            largest = value;

        else if (value < smallest)
            smallest = value;

        scanf(" %f",&value);
    }
        average = sum / count;
        printf("%.2f ",smallest);
        printf("%.2f ",largest);
        printf("%.2f\n",average);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you not simply add the condition to your while loop? `while (value != EOF && value >= -100000 && value <= 100000)`

Comment: scanf() has a return value. Use it.

Comment: @Ben Except that `value` will never be equal to EOF (unless the user just happens to enter something equal to the value of the constant on OP's platform). The return value of `scanf` should be checked.

Comment: That's what I tried first. For some reason nothing happens when I click CTRL + D (I'm on Linux).

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try that wildplasser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you want to handle bad (non-numeric) input?

The simplest approach is probably the following:

```
while ( scanf( "%f", &value ) == 1 && value >= -100000 && value <= 100000 )
{
  // do stuff with value
}
```

This will loop until `value` is outside the specified range *or* `scanf` fails on input, either because of a matching failure (the input isn't numeric) or because EOF has been signaled, or because of some other input error.

Note that the `&&` operator forces left-to-right evaluation; the `scanf` call will be executed and `value` updated before either test.

Also note that if the user types in a number with a non-numeric trailing character like `12.3r`, `scanf` will convert and assign `12.3` to `value` and leave `r` stuck in the input stream, which will cause the *next* call to `scanf` to fail, at which point the loop will exit.

Comment: The system guarantees that only well-formed input will be given to my program, so I won't need to worry about those instances.
Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rubiks "system guarantees that only well-formed input" is information that belongs in your post - but then that changes the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, use the scanf result.
And you don't need to call scanf from 2 locations.
I'd suggest something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float sum, smallest, largest, value, average;
    int count;

    for (count = sum = 0; scanf("%f", &value) == 1; count++) {
        if (value <= -100000 || value >= 100000)
            break;

        sum += value;

        if (count == 0)
            smallest = largest = value;
        else if (value > largest)
            largest = value;
        else if (value < smallest)
            smallest = value;
    }

    if (count) {
        average = sum / count;
        printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", smallest, largest, average);
    } else {
        printf("error, no data processed\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```